# Overriding __dict__() on python class

Tags: python, class

I have a class where I want to get the object back as a dictionary, so I implemented this in the `__dict__()`.  Is this correct?

I figured once I did that, I could then use the `dict` (custom object), and get back the object as a dictionary, but that does not work.

Should you override `__dict__()`?  How can you make it so a custom object can be converted to a dictionary using `dict()`?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`__dict__` is *not* a special method on Python objects. It is used for the attribute dictionary; `dict()` never uses it.

Instead, you could support *iteration*; when `dict()` is passed an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterable) that produces key-value pairs, a new dictionary object with those key-value pairs is produced.

You can provide an iterable by implementing a `__iter__` method, which should return an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator). Implementing that method as a generator function suffices:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, *values):
        self.some_sequence = values

    def __iter__(self):
        for key in self.some_sequence:
            yield (key, 'Value for {}'.format(key))
```

Demo:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self, *values):
...         self.some_sequence = values
...     def __iter__(self):
...         for key in self.some_sequence:
...             yield (key, 'Value for {}'.format(key))
... 
>>> f = Foo('bar', 'baz', 'eggs', 'ham')
>>> dict(f)
{'baz': 'Value for baz', 'eggs': 'Value for eggs', 'bar': 'Value for bar', 'ham': 'Value for ham'}
```

You could also subclass `dict`, or implement the [Mapping abstract class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Mapping), and `dict()` would recognize either and copy keys and values over to a new dictionary object. This is a little more work, but may be worth it if you want your custom class to act like a mapping everywhere else too.

Comment: seems logical, so if you wanted to pass a select set of information back for __iter__ could you use a return {"var1":"val1", ..."varn" : "valn"} instead of yield?

Comment: @josh1234: No, `__iter__` *must* return an iterator; a dictionary is not itself an iterator.

Comment: @josh1234: and you'd need to produce a sequence of key-value pairs. So `iter(somedictionary.items())` is fine, but not `somedictionary` directly.

Comment: @josh1234: the other alternatives are to *subclass* `dict` or to otherwise implement the [`Mapping` abstract type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Mapping).

Answer (score 54):

No. `__dict__` is a method used for introspection - it returns object attributes. What you want is a brand new method, call it `as_dict`, for example - that's the convention. The thing to understand here is that `dict` objects don't need to be necessarily created with `dict` constructor.

Comment: I prefer this answer over the most voted. It's nice to know how `dict` works, but overriding `__iter__` to obtain a dict from an object looks a little hacky to me. It may also have some unintended ramifications.

Comment: I wouldn’t call `__dict__` a method for introspection. It is a descriptor on the class and it’s use goes well beyond introspection; e.g. giving you direct write  access to the attribute namespace of an instance in your code when you have overriden `__setattr__` for example.

Answer (score 7):

The following method will allow an object of the class to be casted to a `dict`:

```
def __iter__(self):
    for key in self.__dict__:
        yield key, getattr(self, key)
```

Comment: This answer was the clearest for me. In my case I supplied a list of keys rather than relying on `self.__dict__`